# Transistor active mode

Tags: transistors, npn, practical

I have been looking on the web but all I found was theory that I couldn't fully understand,nor apply .How can a NPN transistor be switched on in active mode?I would appreciate if you would give a more practical and less theoretical answer.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.  If this is a real world problem, then no transistors need to be abused in the lighting of the LED.  All you need is R2 in series with the LED across the supply.

Comment: It seems I formulated the question in a wrong way , sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [site](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4.html). The page clearly takes you through the working of transistor as a switch, along with regions of operation of transistor in detail. You can then try reading the parameters of BC547 and see how your LED turn on circuit needs to be configured. You can always ask question when you don't understand something specific, and not a generic question.

Some more links [1](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/transistor-switch-bjt/), [2](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/electronics-components-use-a-transistor-as-a-switc.html), [3](http://www.rason.org/Projects/transwit/transwit.htm).

Comment: I understand that when a transistor is in active mode , it does not turn the load fully on.Say , if a load had need of 100mA and the transistor allows only 50 mA ,we say that it works in its active region.Am I correct?

Comment: @Daniel you are right in one context. The transistor’s collector current is proportional to the base current. If Base curretn is made suffciently large, the collector current will be maximum (500 mA, assume!) (Saturation mode). Now, if oyu start reducing the base current (either by increasing the base resistor's value or by reducing te base to emitter voltage, in a common emitter configuration), the collector current starts to drop, say to 50 mA. Now the transitory is in active mode (amplifier mode with gain of beta.)...

Comment: ...In short, The region in the VI characteristic of the transistor where there is a linear relationship between base current and collector current is called active region.

Comment: So active mode is when the transistor allows a collector current between the cut-off Ic and saturation Ic(max allowable current) in a linear context , the load is taken out of equation(max allowable collector current and not max allowable load current)?

Comment: The collector current obviously depends on the collector resistance. When we are talking about collector current, it inherently involves the load.

Comment: Yes , but I am saying that you don't have to run it in saturation mode to fully activate a load.Active mode could be enough.It's about how much Ic current passes trough , not really how much the load wants.

Comment: It depends on the application, whether you want to amplify a signal or turn on an LED.. If the transistor is not in saturation, the VCEsat will be a big number and the load current multiplied to it will give the power dissipation. For a transistor in saturation, VCEsat will almost be zero, hence the power consumption will be negligible.

Comment: But in the context of turning on something , what I said works , no?

Comment: your statement is subjective. take a context, an example.

Comment: Never mind , I looked at the comments and understood what I was  a little confused about.Thank you , your explanations really helped me.

Comment: just to add... whenever we speak about turn on and tun off with respect to transistor it will be cut off and saturation modes only (most of the time). Active mode comes only for amplification or modulation